# how to remove a package which post-installation and pre-removal script fails?

Tags: debian, package-management

I have an issue with the package openqrm.

How do I remove it?

```
root@wl183004:/# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
Setting up openqrm (4.6-ubuntu1) ...
.: 33: Can't open /usr/share/openqrm/etc/openqrm-server.conf
dpkg: error processing openqrm (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openqrm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

root@wl183004:/# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up openqrm (4.6-ubuntu1) ...
.: 33: Can't open /usr/share/openqrm/etc/openqrm-server.conf
dpkg: error processing openqrm (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openqrm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

root@wl183004:/# apt-get remove --purge openqrm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libshadow-ruby1.8 bind9 libopenipmi0 nagios-plugins-basic open-iscsi
  nagios-plugins-standard memcached libupsclient1 collectd-core nagios-images
  bind9utils tftpd-hpa radiusclient1 libdbi0 libphp-adodb collectd libruby
  aoetools facter dhcp3-server open-iscsi-utils liboping0 libmemcached2
  libradius1 libyajl1 nagios-plugins puppet-common puppetmaster
  libopenssl-ruby1.8 libopenssl-ruby libesmtp5 libxmlrpc-ruby
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  openqrm*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 78.2MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
(Reading database ... 313464 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing openqrm ...
.: 32: Can't open /usr/share/openqrm/etc/openqrm-server.conf
dpkg: error processing openqrm (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
.: 33: Can't open /usr/share/openqrm/etc/openqrm-server.conf
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openqrm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@wl183004:/#
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431372/removing-broken-packages-in-ubuntu

Comment: Hi @rogerdpack , there are 8 years between my question and the one you point to. :) Have a nice day.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You might try to upgrade the package before purging it. In some cases, the new package will fix the removal script (`dpkg` is made so that new packages can fix even the transition scripts of old packages).

If that doesn't work, have a look at `/var/lib/dpkg/info/openqrm.postinst` like Kyle suggested, locate the line that fails, comment it out and try to purge again. Repeat until success.

Comment: I've added exit 0 to the begining of openqrm.prerm. it worked. thanks

Comment: but... how do we do this? "locate the line that fails, comment it out"

Comment: Using your favorite editor and sudo

Comment: add `set -x` to the script to see where it fails, cf. http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/debugging-shell-script.html

Comment: I've also had to edit a `/var/lib/dpkg/info/*.prerm` file to get a package to uninstall.  What a design!

Answer (score 24):

The following worked for me:

- rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info/openqrm.*
- rm -rf /usr/share/openqrm
- rm -rf /etc/default/openqrm
- rm -rf /etc/init.d/openqrm
- apt-get purge openqrm

Comment: this worked! Generalized, simply replace "openqrm" with whatever your package name is.

Comment: This helped me to get rid of a broken `apacheds` install, that blocked totally any `apt` command on my system, thanks... we could generalize a little bit more by searching first all the locations of the package with `sudo find / | grep [package name]`, then removing them all, then using `sudo apt-get remove [package name] -purge --auto-remove` (not scriptedly, some of the results might not be to be removed though...)

Answer (score 7):

Just try to touch the missing file. If this is just one file missing file it could be a great
workaround.

```
touch /usr/share/openqrm/etc/openqrm-server.conf
```

Now try to remove the package with apt-get or aptitude.

Comment: This worked - was finally able to remove postfix

Answer (score 3):

Look at /var/lib/dpkg/info/openqrm.postinst and see what it's trying to do

Answer (score -1):

There's a [post here](http://www.khattam.info/solved-subprocess-pre-removal-script-returned-error-exit-status-2-error-2009-08-04.html) about the same kind of error (different package, though).  Have you tried  `dpkg --force-all` yet?